# how to add uilabel value with new value from the picker view

Tags: ios

I have `UITableViewCell` and add a `UILabel` on it.  I am displaying the value on `UILabel` from `UIPickerView`. I am doing this task with this code:

```
(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   NSLog(@"row selected:%ld", (long)row);
   value = _countingarray[row];

   value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[value intValue] +   [_countingarray[row] intValue]];

   [self.mytableview reloadData];
   [self hidePickerView];
}
```

but when I execute it, `UILabel` value increased on other `UITablViewCell` too.

Can you help me how to update `uilabel` values individually according to the cell selected. This is my whole code for my all functionality.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UitableviewcellTableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(position == indexPath.row){
        int row;
        value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[value intValue] + [_countingarray[row] intValue]];
        Cell.nameLabel.text = value;
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
    }else{
        Cell.nameLabel.text = @"value";
    }
    NSLog(@"Position :- %ld   %d", (long)indexPath.row, position);

    return Cell;
}
```

this is tableview cell code where I want to update the value and below code is for picker view.

```
 (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:  (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
  {

    NSLog(@"row selected:%ld", (long)row);
    value = _countingarray[row];

    value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[value intValue] + 
            [_countingarray[row] intValue]];

    [self.mytableview reloadData];
    [self hidePickerView];    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your didSelectRow take one array and add selected value into it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
      NSMutableArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      int index=-1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
    value = _countingarray[row];
    index=index+1;
    [arr1 insertObject:value atIndex:index ];
    NSString *str = [arr1 valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.intValue"];//you will get the sum of all array objects 
    [self.mytableview reloadData];
    [self hidePickerView];

}
```

and show this str value into your tableview.

Comment: should i declare nsmutablearray in didseletect row method, because when i declared it viewdidload method it gives me error of undeclared identifier.

Comment: can i apply some logic on cell for row at index path method.

Comment: you have to declare it your .h file .Sorry it was my mistake.

Comment: it gives me error for array declaration like this :- " Expected ';' at end of declarations list"

Comment: Check you forgot to do ", "somewhere.

Comment: Please help me in my situation if u understand my code probelm

Comment: hello should i wait for your response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98715/discussion-between-sandeep-tomar-and-bhumica).

Comment: hello Bhumica mam, i am still getting problem can you help me plz

Comment: Please discuss in chat

Comment: one more help i need from you. how will i dismiss picker view on button click

Answer (score 0):

In PickerView DidSelect row method just reload that cell which you want instead of reloading the table .

Use this method for reload

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0);
```

And take an array Containing the values you want to set in each label for cell.Also update that array after the pickerDidSelect .

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: What is the issue now ?

Comment: its increasing everywhere on each cell, but when i select the other cell it should start from the initial value.

Comment: you are still reloading the whole table .thats the reason why .and cell for row at index path method will be call each time you scroll .As you are setting always tha "value" .so it is showing for all cell .